# HttpPost returns only part of response body

Tags: android, response, http-post, chunked

I'm performing login on server using HttpPost method.

```
CommonsConnection.initHttpConnection();
HttpResponse response;
String contentOfMyInputStream;

HttpGet initPostMethod = new HttpGet("https://stat.volia.com:8443/ktvinet/index.jsp");
response = CommonsConnection.hc.execute(initPostMethod);

HttpPost Statistics = new HttpPost("https://stat.volia.com:8443/ktvinet/j_security_check");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", "username"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", "password"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "%C2%EE%E9%F2%E8"));

Statistics.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
response = CommonsConnection.hc.execute(Statistics);

HttpGet mainPage = new HttpGet("https://stat.volia.com:8443/ktvinet/main.do");
response = CommonsConnection.hc.execute(mainPage);

contentOfMyInputStream = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

The response I get - body of webpage - is like 1/5 part of webpage, which ends with "...".
Am I missing some parameter for httpclient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you examining the response? if you're looking int he debugger or something similar, it may well truncate long strings, try dumping it in a file.

Comment: That really was only problem of debugger, that can't show full response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Logcat displays only part of long string response.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realized it!